# Why is spam added to the Bing cache of my landing page?

Tags: spam, cache, bing, bing-webmaster-tools

Please search on Bing ["url:testrails.org"](http://www.bing.com/search?q=url%3atestrails.org) and open the [cached page](http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=url%3atestrails.org&d=54048689070214801&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=S48VoNiU9bmf6-I_P-FnrJQJEkWtp3rc). Bing shows random other pages below the content of [my own landing page](http://testrails.org). This is so weird!

This is what I found out so far:

- I have a second domain that I also manage on the Bing Webmaster site which has the same issue.
- And I don't have a third domain managed on the Bing Webmaster site. In general I have other domains. They are not affected.
- The content of one of my domains managed on the Bing Webmaster site is hosted on Bluehost the other on OpenShift.
- Only the landing page (main index.html) is affected. Other pages on the site are not affected.
- The added content seems not to be a part of the actual Bing index. It just shows up in the cache.
- My own page doesn't contain any code that might have a virus etc. (I am a web developer and I checked everything.)
- The added content is actually delivered by Bing as part of the HTML code. It is not related to anything in the browser. (I checked it with different devices, with and without being signed in to my Microsoft account, with and without JavaScript turned on.)

Any ideas?!

Comment: Dang! That is a good one. Could it be that Bing is owned and operated by Microsoft? ;-)

Comment: The "cached spam" seems to vary by simply refreshing the page - it's not static!? It also appears after your closing `</html>` tag.

Comment: It's most likely some kind of bing bug... after refreshing the page  there is content from Washington Post, The Economist etc. Even flickr.com page appeared there.

Comment: Thanks folks! You seem to agree that the cause may lie on Bing's side. I just reported the issue to Bing. Let us see what they can tell.

Comment: Don't forget to add it as an answer here then, would be interesting to hear what caused this, but I doubt they go into detail, more just like thank you for reporting, if anything :)

Comment: @BadrHari Yes, I will. I already got a response that the Product Group will investigate this. Let's see how they respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the reply from the Microsoft Technical Support. They say:

> We would like to update and thank you for reporting your cache page concern to us. Currently our Bing Team is working on a fix but we do not have an ETA yet on when the fix will going to be implemented. Rest assured that this issue does not in any way impact your site's indexation in Bing.

So it is a Bing bug but it is only related to displaying the cache. My tests also showed that the random other pages were not added to the indexed content.